# why VS2012 Coded UI Test records mouse clicks as points

Tags: selenium, coded-ui-tests

i was trying to create simple Coded UI Test in VS2012 for a MVC Web App. I recorded my actions and when i say a generated code i saw my mouse clicks were recorded as points (x,y) where i clicked. I was expecting it should pick the clicked element as html element and simulate click on it. something i saw in selenium. Cant we do this king of a thing without selenium ?

i am looking to write a codedUITest with following steps.

Step 1 : Open a Web Browser.
Step 2 : Navigate to something.Com/something/some/2      what ever
Step 3: Find element e.g. Anchor Tag by name and click it.
Step 4: Wait for page to complete the load and verify a certain verbiage appears on the page     by looking the inner text of some Span or something.

I was expecting the the Code of Step 1 to 3 should already be there and then I added the Assert statement for Step 4.

AM I MISSING SOMETHING ? Or this kind of stuff is only possible in Selenium.

Comment: I believe that is what the record functionality for CodedUI does.  You would need to manually program the maps for finding the elements at runtime based on some DOM selection.  The CodedUI inspector tool does provide some additional options to make these changes.  Personally if I am automating WebApplications I avoid CodedUI...I actually avoid CodedUI for desktop too...(sikuli).  I also dislike the forced structure CodedUI relies on which has to be manually manipulated for each test to create a common map repository that is reused for multiple tests.

Comment: like you said manually maps for finding the elements at runtime based on some DOM selection. Do we have calls for that ? like what is the call to open the web browser and navigate and find a button and click it

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI records coordinates within a control, normally the smallest control containing the point clicked. Hence the recorded coordinates are small numbers. The recorder generates code such as

```
Mouse.Click(uISearchButton, new Point(15, 12));
```

This can often be replaced with a call of

```
Mouse.Click(uISearchButton);
```

The basic reason is that some controls do different things depending on where they are clicked. For example buttons that have little triangles that open menus.

[Microsoft have a blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2012/03/16/faq-why-are-we-using-coordinate-based-actions-in-coded-ui-test.aspx) giving more details about these mouse clicks.